# Getting Null point Exception when Clicking Delete Button in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, delete-file

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
  myViewHolder.mName.setText(downModels.get(i).getName());
    myViewHolder.mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DownloadTask();
        }
    });


myViewHolder.mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String pdfName = downModels.get(i).getName();

        if(pdfName != null) {
            pdfName = pdfName.replace("", "")+".pdf";

            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), pdfName);
            try {
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                Log.e("file","file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

 }
});
```

When Clicked the Delete button, application crashes.

> 2020-03-01 22:50:55.461 16800-16800/com.solutions.rsaggarwal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
>       main Process: com.solutions.rsaggarwal, PID: 16800
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File 
>       android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference
>       at com.solutions.rsaggarwal.MyAdapter$2.onClick(MyAdapter.java:70)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
>       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
>       at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: What is the `context`?

Comment: make sure whether you have set proper findviewbyId of the button in recyclerview item in adapter

Comment: Context context;  and I set proper I'd of button,

Comment: are you setting the context from your activity/fragment in your ```MyAdapter``` constructor.

Comment: I'm setting it from a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `context` you're passing as an argument in your adapter class is null. As an alternative you can use the context that is attached to the `itemView` as below.

```
  Context context = myViewHolder.itemView.getContext();
  File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), pdfName);
  try {
        if (file.exists())
                 file.delete();
         Log.e("file","file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
       } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```